# TeX and Turing Award

Tags: tex-history

**Leslie Lamport**, who created LaTeX, has recently received the prestigious **Turing Award** (see [here](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/lamport_1205376.cfm) and [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/news/features/lamport-031814.aspx)).
An accomplishement in itself, his work on LaTeX is not even the reason why he got the award.

**Donald Knuth**, who created TeX, also received the Turing Award (see [here](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/knuth_1013846.cfm)).

Who else received prestigious prizes and is connected to the TeX world?

Comment: Note: This doesn't belong on meta as while it's not a code question, it's not about TeX-sx, and the meta site is really for the latter case.

Comment: Close voters, how is this off topic?

Comment: @Jubobs: see Joseph Wright's comment above.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap: Joseph’s comment does only speak of Meta.TeX.SX!

Comment: As long as this is closed: [Donald E. Knuth - A.M. Turing Award Winner 1974](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/knuth_1013846.cfm).

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap My point was as Speravir suggests that this should not get migrated to the meta site. The meta sites aren't for 'meta questions about the topic', they are for questions about how the site itself is run.  So either this is on topic for the main site or it's entirely off-topic for us. A suitable meta question would be to explore which of these cases applies!

Comment: @Speravir: Sorry, I think I was reading a little hastily.
@ Jubobs (if you're reading this, I know that only one @ user is notified per comment): I consider it off topic because it's not a code question, and it's not about TeX.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I consider this question on topic because it fits the [tag:tex-history] tag, but I think it may be more appropriate as a community wiki.

Comment: @Jubobs: If you mean that this is an example of `The history and origins of TeX and its variants, their applications, their supporting software (such as fonts or viewers), and their mythology and heraldry`, then I disagree. This has as much connection to TeX as the fall of the Western Roman Empire has to Norse Mythology (in that Attilah the Hun is pertinent to both).

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap People connected to TeX (whether they received awards or not) are very much part of TeX's history. See my answer below, especially Knuth's quote about Steele. If this question is off-topic, then the [tag:tex-history] tag wiki is misleading and should be amended.

Comment: @Jubobs: if you say so. This post is currently a noticeable outlier in the list of questions with that tag: if the community agrees that the description ought to be extended to fit, perhaps that's a good thing to suggest on Meta.

Comment: @JosephWright this Q may be it's borderline on-topic and as Jubobs said a community wiki since there is no specific answer "Who else received prestigious prizes" and with an `Awards` tag

Answer (score 14):

[Guy Steele](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_L._Steele,_Jr.) is an award-winning computer scientist who is connected to TeX.

[image: Guy Steele himself]

Here is the beginning of a [short bio](http://www.codersatwork.com/guy-steele.html) taken from Peter Seibel's book, *Coders at Work*, for which the author interviewed Steele.

> Guy Steele is a true programming polyglot. When I asked him what
> languages he has used seriously he came up with this list: COBOL,
> Fortran, IBM 1130 assembly, PDP-10 machine language, APL, C, C++,
> Bliss, GNAL, Common Lisp, Scheme, Maclisp, S-1 Lisp, *Lisp, C*, Java,
> JavaScript, Tcl, Haskell, FOCAL, BASIC, TECO, and TeX. “Those would be
> the main ones, I guess,” he added.
>
> He had a hand in the creation of both of the major surviving
> general-purpose Lisp dialects: Common Lisp and Scheme. He served on
> the standards bodies that defined Common Lisp, Fortran, C, ECMAScript,
> and Scheme and was recruited by Bill Joy to help write the official
> language specification for Java. He is now at work designing Fortress,
> a new language for high-performance scientific computing.
>
> Steele’s academic career included an AB from Harvard and an SM and PhD
> from MIT. While at MIT he collaborated with Gerald Sussman on a series
> of papers now known as “The Lambda Papers,” which included the
> original definition of the Scheme programming language. He has also
> been a chronicler of hacker culture as one of the original compilers
> of the Jargon File and editor of the book version, The Hacker’s
> Dictionary (subsequently updated and expanded by Eric S. Raymond as
> The New Hacker’s Dictionary). And he played an important role in the
> birth of Emacs and was **one of the first programmers to port Donald
> Knuth’s program TeX**.
>
> Steele is a Fellow of the Association for Computing Machinery and the
> American Academy of Arts and Sciences and a member of the U.S.
> National Academy of Engineering. **He won the ACM’s Grace Murray Hopper
> Award in 1988 and Dr. Dobb’s Excellence in Programming Award in 2005.**

(my emphasis)

Knuth himself, in the interview he gave to Seibel for the same book, describes Steele as influential in the development of TeX (see p597 in *Coders at Work*).

> **Seibel:** You’ve designed some languages yourself—probably the most widely used of which is TeX.
>
> **Knuth:** So TeX is a programming language but I had to put in those features
> kicking and screaming. **Guy Steele**, Terry Winograd, Leslie Lamport, and
> different people needed things when they were using TeX as a front end
> for their material. I think Terry Winograd was writing a book on the
> syntax of natural languages, so he had some really powerful macros
> that he wanted to write in order to make the diagrams in his book.
> That pushed TeX a lot towards becoming a programming language in the
> earliest days.

(my emphasis)

Comment: It's maybe worth mentioning that Guy Steele also worked on the design/evolution of other programming languages like Fortran, C, Java, Scheme, Common Lisp and Javascript :)

Comment: @marczellm Done.

Comment: Related links: [Coders at Work: Reflections on the Craft of Programming by Peter Seibel](http://www.codersatwork.com/) Based on nearly eighty hours of conversations with fifteen all-time great programmers and computer scientists and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/podcast-69/

Comment: @texenthusiast I really enjoyed that book. I should read again, some time. I recommend it to anyone.

Answer (score 6):

Another award-winning computer scientist who Knuth cites as an influence on the early development of TeX is **Terry Winograd**.

[image]

The *Professional Interests* rubric on Winograd's [personal page](http://hci.stanford.edu/winograd/) reads:

> Professor Winograd's focus is on human-computer interaction design and
> the design of technologies for development. He directs the teaching
> programs and HCI research in the Stanford Human-Computer Interaction
> Group, which recently celebrated it's 20th anniversary. He is also a
> founding faculty member of the Hasso Plattner Institute of Design at
> Stanford (the "d.school") and on the faculty of the Center on
> Democracy, Development, and the Rule of Law (CDDRL)
>
> Winograd was a founding member and past president of Computer
> Professionals for Social Responsibility. He is on a number of journal
> editorial boards, including Human Computer Interaction, ACM
> Transactions on Computer Human Interaction, and Informatica. He has
> advised a number of companies started by his students, including
> Google.

He was the recipient of the [2011 SIGCHI Lifetime Research Award](http://www.sigchi.org/about/awards/2011-sigchi-awards#terry-winograd). In Peter Seibel's *Coders at Work*, Knuth refers to Winograd as someone who convinced him to make TeX a full-fledged programming language.

> **Seibel:** You’ve designed some languages yourself—probably the most widely used of which is TeX.
>
> **Knuth:** So TeX is a programming language but I had to put in those features
> kicking and screaming. Guy Steele, **Terry Winograd**, Leslie Lamport, and
> different people needed things when they were using TeX as a front end
> for their material. **I think Terry Winograd was writing a book on the
> syntax of natural languages, so he had some really powerful macros
> that he wanted to write in order to make the diagrams in his book.**
> That pushed TeX a lot towards becoming a programming language in the
> earliest days.

(my emphasis)

Comment: Terry Winograd also (co)wrote [an article (“An indexing facility for TeX”)](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb01-1/winograd-paxton.pdf) in the [very first issue of TUGboat](https://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents1-1.html).